# getName method makes error "Cannot invoke getName () on the array type String []"?

Tags: java

I am newbie with java and trying to write a simple code to test both getName and componentType in one code like this

```java
package class_getcomponenttype;

import java.lang.*;

public class example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = new String[] {"admin"};
        Class arrClass = arr.getClass();
        Class componentType = arrClass.getComponentType();
        if (componentType != null) {
            System.out.println(arr.getClass().getName() + " " + arr.getName());
            System.out.println("ComponentType = " + componentType.getName());
        } else {
            System.out.println("ComponentType is null");
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran this code, it said to me that I had problem at the line `System.out.println(arr.getClass().getName() + " " + arr.getName());`
and the problem is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Cannot invoke getName() on the array type String[]
    at class_getcomponenttype.example.main(example.java:15).
```

As I understand, I could use getName to get the name of the entity represented by Class object, as a String or something like this. So I do not understand why I have this error ?

Sorry for my mistake because I am still a newbie. Could you please give me some suggestions? Thank you very much.

Comment: what do you expect `arr.getName()` to return or do? Neither arrays nor Strings have a method called `getName()` that you could call on them.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS : Thank you for your comment. Now I could understand why my code got that error, but when I delete the `arr.getName()`, it print `[Ljava.lang.String; ` at the 1st line, and I thought that getClass made java.lang, but I still do not understand why "getName" made "String" ? Could you please give me some ideas ? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.String;` is just the class name for a `String[]` (Array of Strings). For `Integer[]` you would get `[Ljava.lang.Integer;` etc. pp.. Now if you want to know why the Array Classes have those types of names (starting with "[L"), you need to ask the people who designed and specified the java language.

Answer (score 0):

Object of type `String[]` does not have a method `getName()`
So your line

```java
System.out.println(arr.getClass().getName() + " " + arr.getName());
```

result in a compilation error due to `arr.getName()` as `arr` is typed as a `String[]` which does not implement this method.